# Is there a way to get the content-length from an HTTP header using libcurl >=7.3.x?

Tags: c, libcurl

I am using the libcurl library to receive an HTTP request. I would like to know the content length of the body so that I can allocate memory. Is there a library function or libcurl library supported way of parsing an HTTP header? I am not quite sure what the most effective way to go about retrieving the content length is when I receive the header and I want to use what is considered to be standard in libcurl. I have consulted [the docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) but have not found anything.

Comment: No need to parse any headers - if you want to handle arriving data yourself, looking at the signature of the way you do this makes it pretty obvious that the size of the content is included in the call, which isn’t too surprising/unexpected: `size_t write_data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);`

Comment: Yes but nmemb is the size passed in on that call of the callback not content length. Unfortunately the protocol I am using requires total length up front.

Comment: `size*nmemb` is the content length of buffer - if it weren’t you wouldn’t be able to download a binary file using libcurl, would you? Chances are one of them will be 1 and the other will be the number of bytes. Try it and see.

Comment: Aren't there situations where this isn't the case?

Comment: Have you heard that one of the important advantages of “Open Source” is that the source is, err, open, so you can check this sort of thing for yourself https://github.com/curl/curl. Or try it and see for yourself from executing a download. But it stands to reason that if libcurl can be used to download any length of file then to cope with files of any length `size*nmemb` must be the number of bytes in the file. Otherwise the received file would be a different (greater) length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `Content-Length` with [CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD_T](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD_T.html) but I wouldn't recommend you rely on that.

1. HTTP doesn't mandate that the header is sent and in fact a huge amount of HTTP responses are sent without the header so the client doesn't know the size before-hand.
2. HTTP responses can be very big so allocating and storing the entire response in memory could be a really bad idea if your client doesn't have full control of what resources it will get.

You said "the protocol I am using requires total length up front", but that doesn't mean that HTTP will provide one for you. You should then *probably* rather first get the HTTP response and figure out the total size before you hand that data on using that second protocol that needs the size upfront!